Local Dapr can't invoke service running in k8s under docker desktop
I have enabled k8s in my docker desktop running on Windows 10.
I've deployed several microservices to this k8s cluster and they all work.  I'm using dapr to perform service invocations between the microservices.  This works with everything running in k8s.
I have a new .NET 8 microservice that I'm testing locally using dapr run -k ... to run.  It loads successfully and I see this in the log at startup:

Updating metadata for appPID: 19976
Updating metadata for app command: dotnet watch run
You're up and running! Both Dapr and your app logs will appear here.

When I use the .NET dapr client to invoke the service, it fails and I see this error information in my logs:

errorCode:ERR_DIRECT_INVOKE
message:failed to invoke, id: k8sServiceName,
err: failed to invoke target k8sServiceName after 3 retries.
Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable
desc = last connection error: connection error: desc = transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 10.1.0.145:50002: i/o timeout

The IP and Port are correct for the k8sServiceName running in k8s.
I can access the endpoints for my services running under k8s via postman.
Any ideas what I might be missing?
I've done port-forwarding for the redis port being used.  Not sure if there are other ports I need to forward.
I've experimented with different port forwarding, but I'm not exactly sure if that's the issue.
I'm also using Consul for local service discovery.
I'm using the latest versions of Dapr, Docker Desktop, and all my other dev tools are up to date using the latest nuget packages.
I also tried using the dapr invoke -a k8sServiceName -m myMethod.  It fails with app ID not found.
Following is the C# code used to use dapr invoke:
    async Task<TResponse> RequestAsyncTest<TRequest, TResponse>(string appId, string methodName, TRequest request, HttpMethod httpMethod = default, string apiKey = default)
        {
            // this.daprClient is an instance of Dapr.Client.DaprClient from the Dapr.Client by dapr.io nuget package.
            using var httpRequest = this.daprClient.CreateInvokeMethodRequest(httpMethod, appId, methodName, request);
            using var response = await this.daprClient.InvokeMethodWithResponseAsync(httpRequest);
            var resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                this.logger.LogError($"Calling {appId} {methodName} error response: {response}\nResult: {resultContent}\nRequest:{httpRequest}");
            }

            var resultString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(resultString, converters);
            return result;
        }

When running locally, I'm using this command line:
"dapr run -k --app-protocol https --enable-app-health-check --enable-profiling --app-id myAppId --app-port 44381 --resources-path \"..\\Solution Items\\Dapr\" --config \"..\\Solution Items\\Dapr\\daprConfig.yaml\" dotnet watch run"

Dapr.yml file looks like this:
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: pubsub-servicebus
spec:
  type: pubsub.redis
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: localhost:6379
  - name: redisPassword
    value: "redisPasswordGoesHere"
---
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: consul
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: state.consul
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: datacenter
    value: dc1 # Required. Example: dc1
  - name: httpAddr
    value: host.docker.internal:8500

daprConfig.yml looks like this
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: daprconfig-myAppId
spec:
  nameResolution:
    version: v1
    component: "consul"
    configuration:
      client:
        address: host.docker.internal:8500
      selfRegister: true
      checks:
        - name: "Dapr Health Status-myAppId"
          checkID: "daprHealth:myAppId"
          http: "http://host.docker.internal:51044/systeminfo/configinfo"
          interval: "15m"
          timeout: "300s"
          deregisterCriticalServiceAfter: "2m"

I can post the k8s.yml file for the microservice running in k8s if that would be useful.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Edited and added code.
